# Video downloader failing to download a youtube video

Tags: python, tkinter

so i was creating a simple youtube video downloader but it seems to be failing to download.

Here is the source code:

```
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pafy
import pygame


#Functions
def play_audio():
    # initialize pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()
    # load audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.load('Before the Beginning.mp3')
    # play audio
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def pause_play_audio():
    # initialize pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()
    # check if music is playing
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        # pause audio
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    else:
        # resume audio
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()


def select_video_path():
    #allows user to select a path from the explorer
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    path_label.config(text=path)

def select_playlist_path():
    #allows user to select a path from the explorer
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    path_labelPL.config(text=path)
    



def download_video():
    #get user link
    get_link = link_field.get()
    #get selected path
    user_path = path_label.cget("text")
    screen.title('Downloading...')

    try:
        #Download Video
        video = pafy.new(get_link)
        bestaudio = video.getbestaudio(preftype="mp3")
        download_result = bestaudio.download()

        # Check if the download was successful
        if download_result:
            filename = download_result
            # move file to selected directory
            shutil.move(filename, f"{user_path}/{bestaudio.title}.mp3")
            screen.title('Download Complete! Download Another Video...')
        else:
            screen.title('Failed to Download Video...')
            raise Exception("The download method did not return a file name.")
    except Exception as e:
        screen.title('Failed to Download Video...')
        print(f"Error while downloading the video: {e}")


def download_playlist():
    #get user link
    get_link = link_fieldPL.get()
    #get selected path
    user_path = path_labelPL.cget("text")
    screen.title('Downloading...')

    try:
        #Download Playlist
        playlist = pafy.get_playlist(get_link)
        for video in playlist["items"]:
            v = pafy.new(video["pafy"].videoid)
            bestaudio = v.getbestaudio(preftype="mp3")
            filename = bestaudio.download()

            #move file to selected directory
            shutil.move(filename, f"{user_path}/{bestaudio.title}.mp3")
        screen.title('Download Complete! Download Another Playlist...')
    except Exception as e:
        screen.title('Failed to Download Playlist...')
        print(f"An error occurred while downloading the playlist: {e}")




screen = Tk()
title = screen.title("Dave's Youtube Video Downloader")
canvas = Canvas(screen, width=500, height=800)
canvas.pack()

#image logo
logo_img = PhotoImage(file='download.png')
#resize
logo_img = logo_img.subsample(2, 2)
canvas.create_image(250, 80, image=logo_img)

#link field
link_field = Entry(screen, width=40, font=('Arial', 15) )
link_label = Label(screen, text="Enter Video Link Below: ", font=('Arial', 15))


link_fieldPL = Entry(screen, width=40, font=('Arial', 15) )
link_labelPL = Label(screen, text="Enter Playlist Link Below: ", font=('Arial', 15))


#Select Path for saving the file
path_label = Label(screen, text="Select Path For Download", font=('Arial', 15))
select_btn =  Button(screen, text="Select Path", bg='crimson', padx='22', pady='5',font=('Arial', 15), fg='#fff', command=select_video_path)
#Add to window
canvas.create_window(250, 280, window=path_label)
canvas.create_window(250, 330, window=select_btn)

#Add widgets to window 
canvas.create_window(250, 170, window=link_label)
canvas.create_window(250, 220, window=link_field)

canvas.create_window(250, 460, window=link_labelPL)
canvas.create_window(250, 510, window=link_fieldPL)

#Download btns
download_btn = Button(screen, text="Download Video",bg='green', padx='22', pady='5',font=('Arial', 15), fg='#fff', command=download_video)
#add to canvas
canvas.create_window(250, 390, window=download_btn)

path_labelPL = Label(screen, text="Select Path For Download", font=('Arial', 15))
select_btnPL =  Button(screen, text="Select Path", bg='crimson', padx='22', pady='5',font=('Arial', 15), fg='#fff', command=select_playlist_path)
#Add to window
canvas.create_window(250, 580, window=path_labelPL)
canvas.create_window(250, 630, window=select_btnPL)

#Download btns
download_btnPL = Button(screen, text="Download Video",bg='green', padx='22', pady='5',font=('Arial', 15), fg='#fff', command=download_playlist)
#add to canvas
canvas.create_window(250, 690, window=download_btnPL)

#create button
pause_play_button = tk.Button(screen, text='Play', command=play_audio)
pause_play_button.pack()
canvas.create_window(250, 730, window=pause_play_button)

screen.mainloop()
```

maybe someone has an idea on why i could be failing to download ? You response would be appreciated

I was trying to download a video on youtube and i modified the code to download in mp3 format and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Nobody here knows what you mean by "not working", be more specific

Comment: sorry I meant that its not downloading in mp3 format. There is another version of this code that downloads in mp4 and its works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pafy is outdated to youtube video download. Try pytube or youtubedl.

[Pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/)

```
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG12hJ3s6KI').streams.first().download()
```